# Alignment of underbraces

Tags: spacing

I want to change the layout of this. The two `\underbrace` should have the same height and the distances should be equal.

I hope you can teach me how to do this.

Thank you a lot!

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newcommand{\vin}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{-90}{$\in$}}

\begin{document}
$$\underbrace{f^{12}}_{\substack{\vin\\{\cal M}_{12k}(\Gamma)}}\cdot\underbrace{\Delta^{-k}}_{\substack{\vin\\{\cal M}_{-12k}(\Gamma)}}\in{\cal S}_{0}(\Gamma)=\{0\}$$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\vphantom` can be used to reserve the vertical space for the `f` with descender for the second brace:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand{\vin}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{-90}{$\in$}}

\begin{document}
\[
  \underbrace{f^{12}}_{\substack{\vin\\{\cal M}_{12k}(\Gamma)}}\cdot
  \underbrace{\vphantom{f}\Delta^{-k}}_{\substack{\vin\\{\cal M}_{-12k}(\Gamma)}}
  \in{\cal S}_{0}(\Gamma)=\{0\}
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

BTW: [Why is `\[` … `\]` preferable to `$$` … `$$`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/16967)

Answer (score 3):

Add `\vphantom{f}` in the argument to the second `\underbrace`, so you equalize the depths.

Some notes.

1. I added a better definition for `\vin`, so it appears smaller in `\substack`
2. I added braces around the `\underbrace` constructions, so as to make the spacing better (not really relevant here, but in other situations it can be)
3. `$$` should never be used in LaTeX (from day one), see [Why is \[ ... \] preferable to $$ ... $$?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/16967)
4. The syntax `{\cal M}` has been deprecated for more than twenty years.

Here's the code:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newcommand{\vin}{\mathpalette\dovin\relax}
\newcommand{\dovin}[2]{%
  \rotatebox[origin=c]{-90}{$#1\in$}%
}

\begin{document}
\[
{\underbrace{f^{12}}_{\substack{\vin\\\mathcal{M}_{12k}(\Gamma)}}}
\cdot
{\underbrace{\vphantom{f}\Delta^{-k}}_{\substack{\vin\\\mathcal{M}_{-12k}(\Gamma)}}}
\in\mathcal{S}_{0}(\Gamma)=\{0\}
\]
\end{document}
```

Actually the only necessary packages are `amsmath` and `graphicx`.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newcommand{\vin}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{-90}{$\in$}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
    \underbrace{f^{12}}_{\substack{\vin\\{\cal M}_{12k}(\Gamma)}}\cdot\underbrace{\vphantom{f^{12}}\Delta^{-k}}_{\substack{\vin\\{\cal M}_{-12k}(\Gamma)}}\in{\cal S}_{0}(\Gamma)=\{0\}
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

One could use `\makebox` with `\strut` to create unform extra height:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newcommand{\vin}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{-90}{$\in$}}
\newcommand*{\myBox}[1]{\makebox{\strut #1}}

\begin{document}

\[ \underbrace{\myBox{$f^{12}$}}_{\substack{\vin\\{\cal M}_{12k}(\Gamma)}}
\cdot\underbrace{\myBox{$\Delta^{-k}$}}_{\substack{\vin\\{\cal M}_{-12k}
(\Gamma)}}\in{\cal S}_{0}(\Gamma)=\{0\} \]

\end{document}
```

If you want to customize the space you could design your own strut.

Comment: Oops, just saw other answers that are more efficient.